# Best way to resize font sizes for different devices automatically?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

So, i have many labels in my app, and like everything, they have auto-layout, and it works great but for the text inside them. The label layouts as expected, but the text inside them gets cut in smaller devices.

To avoid that, i tried using AutoShrink option in interface build, but it got really messed as you can see in the pictures:

[iPhone 7 simulation without AutoShrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnlT5.png)

[iPhone SE simulation without AutoShrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twBRp.png)

[iPhone SE simulation with AutoShrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bm13.png)

So, as you can see, all labels shrinks differently from each other, resulting in texts with different sizes breaking the App Harmony and design.

What's the best approach to deal with this situation? How can I make that if I need to shrink one label, all of them get shrink to the same size?

Comment: This may be overkill, but for the last two months "Swift Talk" has been building a form library. https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E118-introduction-prototype I *think* this episode is free - every other one is - but I like what they are doing. The idea is not to change the font size all the time, but rather to alter the layout instead when either (a) you don't have the screen space or (b) the user needs a larger font size a la Dynamic Type. Barring that? Code for things, and that can get messy quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth?language=swift) and [minimumScaleFactor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor?language=swift):

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

This creates a text smaller for long strings.

Also you can add more lines for label, using [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines?language=swift).
I think first solution is better for you.